MFC VC++ Accelerator and menu item not display short key and function execution in CMDIFrameWndEx class
I am a new developer working with MFC and VC++ development, and I am encountering an issue with adding a shortcut key to a menu item and executing its function. I have tried to display the shortcut key in the menu during runtime, but it doesn't appear. I am using the '\t' notation to add the shortcut key in the caption area. Additionally, I have set up an accelerator table for the shortcut key functionality, but I am unable to execute it.


Try cleaning the data in the registry, recorded by previous versions of the application. They are stored under \HKCU\SOFTWARE\Local AppWizard-Generated Applications\AppName, if you haven't changed the path in CYourMFCApp::InitInstance() (the SetRegistryKey() call) - you typically change it to CompanyName (it seems AppName is appended automatically). Remove the whole AppName tree. The \t notation should be working, not sure about the accelerator with only a simple letter and no modifier.
